# #include confusion and classes

Tags: c++, class, include

I have been making several games with the Allegro API and C++. I have also been putting all my classes in 1 big main.cpp file. I tried many times to make .h and .cpp files, but my big problem is I have trouble with #including at the right place. For example, I want all my classes to access the allegro library without #including allegro.h everywhere. Could someone please explain how to correctly #include things. In .Net, everything seems to come together, but in c++ one thing cannot be used before it is included. Is there also a way to globally include something throughout my entire program? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want all my classes to access the allegro library without #including allegro.h everywhere.

Why?  That is how you do it in C++ land.

> Could someone please explain how to correctly #include things. In .Net, everything seems to come together, but in c++ one thing cannot be used before it is included

Conceptually, in .NET, it is not much different at all.  You still have to place "using " at the top.  The difference there is that, in .NET, you could also write this every time if you wanted to:

```
void Foo( System.Drawing.Drawing2D.BitmapData bData ) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

A common way to do this is to have a master include file that includes all of the others in the correct order.  This works especially well if you use precompiled headers so

in precomp.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <allegro.h>
.. etc.
```

in myfile.cpp

```
#include "precomp.h"
```

in myfile2.cpp

```
#include "precomp.h"
```

and so on.